# How to traverse a hash in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about hashes in Javascript.  I am playing with this simple script ...

```
<p>try it</p>

<script>
var obj = {13: true, 72: true, 900: true};

for each (var item in obj) {
  console.log('hi there');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

... but I keep getting the error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.
How can I traverse `obj` in the above javascript?

Comment: Remove `each`. It's just `for( item in obj)`.

Comment: It seems like you didn't search the web for that....

Comment: Seems to be getting a lot on down votes.  Please delete the question.

Comment: I did find this from web search https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Comment: @RedCricket The first sentence literally says "The for each...in statement is deprecated".

Answer (score 2):

> The for each[...] statement is deprecated

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in).

Removing `each` does the trick:

```
for (item in obj)
{
    console.log("item: "+item +", value: "+obj[item]);
}
```